Поэтапное заполнение дуги окружности в зависимости от передаваемого значения из VUE
Не догоняю как реализовать заполнение вектора в зависимости от значения переменной. Есть вектор круга, его нужно заполнять красным цветом в зависимости от значения "{{ characters[i].mainLVL }}". В VUE я написал - mailLVL: 0; Буду очень сильно благодарен тому кто поможет! Если что это кусок из интерфейса. Ниже приложил скриншот как должно заполнятся
<div class="vectorlevel" width="100%" height="100%">
                <svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M0 60C0 93.1371 26.8629 120 60 120C93.1371 120 120 93.1371 120 60C120 26.8629 93.1371 0 60 0C26.8629 0 0 26.8629 0 60ZM111 60C111 88.1665 88.1665 111 60 111C31.8335 111 9 88.1665 9 60C9 31.8335 31.8335 9 60 9C88.1665 9 111 31.8335 111 60Z" fill="#191A1E" fill-opacity="0.7"/>
                    <text x="50%"
                          y="50%"
                          text-anchor="middle"
                          font-style="normal"
                          font-family="Gilroy"
                          font-weight="700"
                          line-height="36"
                          font-size="30"
                          fill="white">
                        {{ characters[i].mainLVL }}
                    </text>
                    <text 
                          x="50%" 
                          y="65%"  
                          text-anchor="middle" 
                          font-style="normal"
                          font-family="Gilroy"
                          font-weight= "600"
                          line-height="21"
                          font-size="18" 
                          fill="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)">
                          Уровень
                    </text>
                </svg>
            </div>


VUE JS:    var characterInfo = new Vue({
el: "#characterInfo",
data: {
    show: false,
    mainLVL: 0,

database: mainLVL: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            defaultValue: 0,
            allowNull: false,



как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример


нужно реализовать само заполнение в зависимости от уровня игрока и
установив максимальный.

Длина всей окружности = 320px
Допустим у нас 8 уровней игры, тогда длина одного сектора (уровня)
равна 320 / 8 = 40
Для заполнения окружности в зависимости от уровня игрока воспользуемся
stroke-dasharray= dash gap, где
dash - длина черты
gap - пробел
При stroke-dasharray= 40 320, будет заполнен первый сектор окружности, что соответствует первому уровню.


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 0 120 120"  >
    
  <path class="trace" transform="rotate(-90 60 60)" fill="#1A1B20" stroke="grey" stroke-width="6" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="320" 
    d="M111 60A51 51 0 1 1 9 60a51 51 0 0 1 102 0z" />

 <path class="level" transform="rotate(-90 60 60)" fill="#1A1B20" stroke-dashoffset="320"
    stroke-dasharray="40 280" stroke="#BE1018" stroke-width="6"
     d="M111 60A51 51 0 1 1 9 60a51 51 0 0 1 102 0z" />
    <text x="50%" y="50%" stroke="white" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Gilroy" font-weight= "600" font-size="18"  >Уровень 1 </text>
  
  </svg>



Level2
stroke-dasharray="80 240"


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 0 120 120"  >
    
  <path class="trace" transform="rotate(-90 60 60)" fill="#1A1B20" stroke="grey" stroke-width="6" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="320" 
    d="M111 60A51 51 0 1 1 9 60a51 51 0 0 1 102 0z" />

 <path class="level" transform="rotate(-90 60 60)" fill="#1A1B20" stroke-dashoffset="320"
    stroke-dasharray="80 240" stroke="#BE1018" stroke-width="6"
     d="M111 60A51 51 0 1 1 9 60a51 51 0 0 1 102 0z" />
   
 
   <text x="50%" y="50%" stroke="white" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Gilroy" font-weight= "600" font-size="18"  >Уровень 2 </text>
  
  </svg>



Level3
stroke-dasharray="120 200"


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 0 120 120"  >
    
  <path class="trace" transform="rotate(-90 60 60)" fill="#1A1B20" stroke="grey" stroke-width="6" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="320" 
    d="M111 60A51 51 0 1 1 9 60a51 51 0 0 1 102 0z" />

 <path class="level" transform="rotate(-90 60 60)" fill="#1A1B20" stroke-dashoffset="320"
    stroke-dasharray="120 200" stroke="#BE1018" stroke-width="6"
     d="M111 60A51 51 0 1 1 9 60a51 51 0 0 1 102 0z" />
   
 
   <text x="50%" y="50%" stroke="white" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Gilroy" font-weight= "600" font-size="18"  >Уровень 3 </text>
  
  </svg>



Level4
stroke-dasharray="160 160"


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 0 120 120"  >
    
  <path class="trace" transform="rotate(-90 60 60)" fill="#1A1B20" stroke="grey" stroke-width="6" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="320" 
    d="M111 60A51 51 0 1 1 9 60a51 51 0 0 1 102 0z" />
 <path class="level" transform="rotate(-90 60 60)" fill="#1A1B20" stroke-dashoffset="320"
    stroke-dasharray="160 160" stroke="#BE1018" stroke-width="6"
     d="M111 60A51 51 0 1 1 9 60a51 51 0 0 1 102 0z" />
   <text x="50%" y="50%" stroke="white" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Gilroy" font-weight= "600" font-size="18"  >Уровень 4 </text>
  
  </svg>



Level5
stroke-dasharray="200 120"


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="240" height="240" viewBox="0 0 120 120"  >
    
  <path class="trace" transform="rotate(-90 60 60)" fill="#1A1B20" stroke="grey" stroke-width="6" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="320" 
    d="M111 60A51 51 0 1 1 9 60a51 51 0 0 1 102 0z" />
 <path class="level" transform="rotate(-90 60 60)" fill="#1A1B20" stroke-dashoffset="320"
    stroke-dasharray="200 120" stroke="#BE1018" stroke-width="6"
     d="M111 60A51 51 0 1 1 9 60a51 51 0 0 1 102 0z" />
 
   <text x="50%" y="50%" stroke="white" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Gilroy" font-weight= "600" font-size="18"  >Уровень 5 </text>
  
  </svg>




Спасибо большое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt за простое понятное решение! Взял себе для загрузчиков/%исполнения и т.д. Конечно в идеале хочется иметь сектора круга))) возможно разного цвета или градиент (легко реализуемые с Vue3).

Я "пошерстил" немного и нашел - как рисовать полные сектора круга SVG. Если кому интересно  https://askdev.ru/q/kak-narisovat-sektor-kruga-v-css-39373/

@Михаил Я вас приветствую. Приятно познакомиться. Конечно в идеале хочется иметь сектора круга))) У вас есть возможность задать отдельный вопрос. Напишите подробней в заданном вопросе, что вы хотите получить в итоге. Обязательно укажите метку svg я тогда точно увижу ваш вопрос, остальные метки по вкусу.

@Михаил Я "пошерстил" немного и нашел - как рисовать полные сектора круга SVG  Я бы посоветовал вам искать конкретно на stackoverflow. Так как другие ресурсы просто копируют готовые решения с нашего ресурса и если у вас возникнет дополнительный вопрос, то они конечно же не смогут ответить вам.
Спрашивайте у "авторов" а не у копи-пастеров:)
Образец заполнения вопроса
https://i.sstatic.net/wzi4gZY8.png

Анимация заполнения контура для существующего path невозможна т.к фигура имеет двойной контур
см. рисунок ниже:


Для реализации анимации необходимо удалить один контур, лучше удалить
внешний контур. См. красные стрелки

.

Теперь необходимо сохранить файл в формате *.svg

Далее провести оптимизацию файла с помощью SVGOMG

Код:


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="120" height="120"  style="background:#1D1F25">
  <path d="M111 60A51 51 0 1 1 9 60a51 51 0 0 1 102 0z" style="stroke:#BE1018;stroke-width:8"/>
  </svg>




Для выполнения анимации заполнения контура необходимо узнать
максимальную длину. Делается это с помощью метода JS:
getTotalLength()



let path = document.querySelector(".shape");
let length = path.getTotalLength();
console.log(length);
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="120" height="120"  style="background:#1D1F25">
  <path class="shape" d="M111 60A51 51 0 1 1 9 60a51 51 0 0 1 102 0z" style="stroke:#BE1018;stroke-width:8"/>
  </svg>



Длина path: 320.48773193359375 ~ 320.5 px
Это значение будет использовано в анимации заполнения path
Код:


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"  style="background:#1D1F25">
    
  <path class="shape" stroke-dashoffset="320.5" stroke-dasharray="320.5" transform="rotate(-90 60 60)" d="M111 60A51 51 0 1 1 9 60a51 51 0 0 1 102 0z" style="stroke:#BE1018;stroke-width:8">
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"  dur="7s" values="320.5;0"  repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path> 
   <text x="50%" y="50%" stroke="white" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Gilroy" font-weight= "600" font-size="22"  >Уровень </text>
  
  </svg>




Приветствую, благодарю за развёрнутый ответ, но мой вопрос так и не решён к сожалению. Мне нужно узнать как реализовать заполнение вектора в зависимости от уровня игрока, то есть значения "mainLVL"

Данный функционал реализуется в интерфейсе, который игрок видит один раз за сессию. Это информация о персонаже и там по факту нету никаких анимаций, нужно реализовать само заполнение в зависимости от уровня игрока и установив максимальный. За контур не знал, благодарю, что расписали.

@peirw Что-то нужно добавить, изменит?. Могу второй пример написать без анимации, где заполнение будет зависеть от  положения движка в инпуте

@peirw Посмотрите ответ2
